# Convergence of $f(g_n(x_n)) \rightarrow f(g(x))$

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, banach-spaces

Let $(x_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence in $\mathbb{R}^d$ such that $x_n \rightarrow x \in \mathbb{R}^d$ ($n\rightarrow \infty$). And $f,g,g_n\in C^1(\mathbb{R}^d,\mathbb{R}^d)$ such that :
$$f(g_n(y))\rightarrow f(g(y)), \,\, \forall y \in \mathbb{R}^d.$$
My question is the following :
Can we deduce that :
$$f(g_n(x_n)) \rightarrow f(g(x)).\,\, (n\rightarrow \infty)$$
Or we'll have to verify other hypothesis ?

Answer (score 2):

Without more assumption, this may be false. If you add the hypothesis that $f\circ g_n$ *uniformly* converges to $f \circ g$, then it would be correct.